# Why are my background images being delayed?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm using an item template in Sencha Touch 2.1.1 to show a status, a pic and some details about the user as an item in a List.  When I load the page, I'm seeing a delay in loading all the pics except the first one which is taking about as long as the JSONP calls to pull the status.  You can see that [here](http://screencast.com/t/8hbejuvMkkCm).

My template is pretty straightforward:

```
    itemTpl: [
        "<div class='listView people'>",
        "   <tpl if='workforceID != undefined'>",
        "       <tpl if='workforceID == \"phind\" || workforceID == \"NULL\"'>",
        "           <div class='avatar notFound user'></div>",
        "       <tpl else>",
        "     <tpl if='presence != undefined && presence != null && getAvailability(presence) == \"Available\"'><div class='avatar status available' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);'><span></span></div>",
          "          <tpl elseif='presence != undefined && presence != null && getAvailability(presence) == \"Busy\"'><div class='avatar status busy' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);'><span></span></div>",
          "          <tpl elseif='presence != undefined && presence != null && getAvailability(presence) == \"Away\"'><div class='avatar status away' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);'><span></span></div>",
          "          <tpl elseif='presence != undefined && presence != null && getAvailability(presence) == \"Unavailable\"'><div class='avatar status unavailable' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);'><span><em></em></span></div>",
          "          <tpl elseif='presence != undefined && presence != null && getAvailability(presence) == \"Offline\"'><div class='avatar status offline' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);'><span></span></div>",
          "          <tpl elseif='presence != undefined && presence != null && getAvailability(presence) == \"Do Not Disturb\"'><div class='avatar status dnd' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);''><span><em></em></span></div>",
          "     <tpl else>",
          "         <div class='avatar status offline' style='background-image: url(https://services.xxx.com/emppics/{workforceID}.jpg);'><span><em></em></span></div>",
          "     </tpl>",
        "       </tpl>",
        "   </tpl>",
        "   <ul class='data'>",
        "      <li><h3><strong>{fullName}</strong></h3></li>",
        "      <tpl if='title != undefined && title != null'><li><span class=\"userTitle\">{title}</span></li></tpl>",
        "      <tpl if='roomNumber != undefined && roomNumber != null && roomNumber != \"\"'><li><span class=\"userOffice\">Office: {roomNumber}</span></li></tpl>",
        "   </ul>",
        "</div>"
    ]
```

And the Ajax call for the status is like this:

```
function getUserPresence (record) {
    var email = record.get('mail');
    if (email && email !== 'NULL') { // Need to actually check for text value of NULL :(
        // Get Users' Presence
        Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: Global.presenceUrl + encodeURIComponent(email),
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            disableCaching: false,
            success: function (result, request) {
                if (result) {
                    var presence = result.Availability;
                    record.set('presence', presence);
                }
            },
            failure: function () {
                console.log('Unable to obtain Lync presence at this time');
            },
            timeout: 15000, //if no response something is wrong and just cancel
            scope: this
        });
    }
}
```

If I pull the JSONP call, the pictures of course load right away, so I'm not sure why is the JSONP call blocking the load of the background images.  Shouldn't the browser go get the images irresepctive of how long it takes to make the JSONP calls?

Comment: I can't say definitively, but the way JSONP works is by inserting a script tag to complete the request. Perhaps the browser is blocking any images loading until the script tag has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was not to use CSS but instead the `<img>` tag.  So now my code turns into:

```
<div class='avatar status available'><img onerror='imgError(this)' src='https://services.xxx.com/pics/{id}.jpg'/></div>
```

This results in the images being loaded as expected without being blocked and I get the benefit of checking for errors if the image is bad to send a default image:

```
function imgError (image) {
    image.onerror = function () {
        this.parent().addClass('user');
    }
    image.src = "/resources/img/user.png";
    return true;
}
```